# Difference between MailServiceUtil.sendEmail() and MailEngine.send()

Tags: email, service, liferay

Which of these methods is recommended?

Is any one of these methods outdated?

Do both use internally auth properties set in the portal?

I read the source for both methods, and while MailEngine is a high level abstraction of typical transport, send functionality, etc; MailLocalService uses beanLocator for an external Service.

Which one is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MailEngine` is in `util-java.jar`, in Liferay's `WEB-INF/lib`, so you can't access it from your plugins (other than `ext-plugin`). For this reason consider it an implementation detail with no guaranteed or implied stability.

`MailServiceUtil` is the API service front-end class. This is part of the API and you can reasonably expect it to be quite stable. And you can use it from your plugins as well.